# stop recv socket bluetooth data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I would like to get data from my sdr USB plug on my RPI3 directly on my smartphone. With the function `samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)`, I can easily get samples in my loop (while (1)). Now my job is to change the center frequency by bluetooth with an android application. The problem is actually: I can't receive new data from my key, I have no problem to change value with the structure : `try...`

But impossible to get new value with my function `samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)` because the function `data=client_sock.recv(1024)` block my loop if she don't have data. But this is not what I want. I want to get data from my `sdr.read_samples` and if she detect new data from my phone then she is running.

```
from pylab import*
from rtlsdr import*
from bluetooth import*
import sys

#configure device
sdr= RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3])
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2])
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1])
NFFT=33

#Bluetooth connection

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()

while(1):
        samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6,    Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)
        tab_freq=(result[1]/1e6) 
        value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
        value_list=[format(float(v), ".10f") for v in value_freq.split()]
        value_freq2= "\n".join(value_list)
        tab_pxx=result[0]
        value_pxx=str(tab_pxx)[1:-1]
        client_sock.send(value_freq2+'\n'+'\n'.join(value_pxx.split()))

            try:
                data=client_sock.recv(1024)
                if len(data)==0: break
                data2=float(data)
                a=data2
            except IOError:
                pass
```

How can I solve this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with : `except Bluetooth:`